# Pushing string into array based on arraykey in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, graph

I have the following dataset for a graph I am working on. I want to push data into the the two keys: `labels[]` and `data[]`. I do not want additional inputs in the main array.

```
var array = {
    labels: ["Jan","Feb","March"],
    datasets: [{
        label: "Electronics",
        fillColor: "rgba(210, 214, 222, 1)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(210, 214, 222, 1)",
        pointColor: "rgba(210, 214, 222, 1)",
        pointStrokeColor: "#c1c7d1",
        pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
        pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        data: ["22","48","32"]
    },]
};
```

Shouldn't `array.push({'labels': 'April'});`  add the string "April" to the key called labels?

I get the following error `array.push is not a function`. I need my graph to change depending on the information I push into the array. labels: will be the X axis, and data: will be the Y axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this instead:

```
array.labels.push("April");
console.log(array.labels);
```

The structure `array = {}` is not an array it is an Object with two fields:

```
labels
datasets
```

Both of these two fields are arrays which you can access as:

```
array.labels
array.datasets
```

Now on these two array fields you can apply any of the array functions.

Comment: You are absolutely right! I actually found the solution right after I posted this question. I will accept your answer when time is up (Have to wait 8 minutes). I am not used to the javascript syntax

Thanks for the response